# Change Color of Stream/Layer in d3 Streamgraph

Tags: d3.js, stream-graph

With reference to following Implementation of Streamgraph
http://bl.ocks.org/WillTurman/4631136
If we have 8 Keys then there will be 8 Layers mapped to 8 different colors.

Now If we have the following dataset:

```
    [T1][T2][T3][T4]
    [ 1][ 2][--][--]
    [ 3][ 4][ 5][--]
    [ 6][--][--][17]
    [ 7][--][--][--]
    [ 8][ 9][10][11]
    [--][13][--][--]
    [--][--][15][16]
Here 1-16 are datapoints with weight x
-- are null datapoints with no weight
```

I need to implement the above table with the following Criteria:

1. 1 & 2 be Color A
2. 3,4,5 be Color B
3. 6 be Color C
4. 17 be Color D
5. 7 be Color E
6. 8,9,10,11 be Color F
7. 13 be Color G
8. 15,16 be Color H

So How should I assign different color to the same layer

Can the same layer map to different color?
by giving the following input parameter:

Layer/Key
Date
Value
 
Color

Comment: If I understand you correctly you could use an [ordinal scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales).  Pass in an array of numbers as your input (domain) and map them to the colours in the output (range).

Comment: @user1614080
Thanks for response.
I didnot get how should I map the numbers to color which ultimately maps to Layer.

Kindly Look at this Image
http://postimg.org/image/mn3imv4if/

Here Each Color in a new Layer or a New Key

The Layer succeeding the set of Layers shows a downfall effect which I dont want

So how should I implement stream graph which ll remove this effect

Can the same layer map to different color?
by giving the following input parameter:
 
Layer/Key<br/>
Date<br/>
Value<br/> 
Color<br/>